# Proving that a function of pairwise distinct triples of complex numbers is homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

So, I have a function that goes as following.

$$f(a,b,c)=\left(a,b-a,\frac{c-a}{b-a}\right)$$My goals is to show that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and that it also admits a continuous inverse. Given that $X=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{C}^3\mid a\neq b\neq c\neq a\}$ is the set of distinct triples in $\mathbb{C}$. Where each $(a,b,c)$ determines a triangle in the plane $\Delta abc$. Where $Y=\mathbb{C}\times (\mathbb{C}-\{0\})\times (\mathbb{C}-\{0,1\})$ is the set of triples in $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{C}^3$ with $y\neq 0$ and $z\notin \{0,1\}$. Where $\mathbb{C}^3$ be the usual metric topology and $X,Y$ being subspace topologies. I'm not sure where to start, any help would be highly appreciated.

**Attempt**

So, to show that $f$ is continuous we have to show that if $U\in \mathcal{T}_Y\implies f^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal{T}_X$. My initial thought was to split this into components to make it easier. Where $f_1(a,b,c)=a,f_2(a,b,c)=b-a$ and $f_3(a,b,c)=(c-a)/(b-a)$. Let's take $f_2(a,b,c)$, now let $(u,v,w)\in X$ then $|f_2(a,b,c)-f_2(u,v,w)|=|(b-a)-(u-v)|\leq |b-a|+|u-v|\leq 2\sqrt{(b-a)^2+(u-v)^2}$. I'm not sure if I'm on the right path.

**Edit**

I'm currently doing an introductory course in topology and complex analysis as my two math modules this semester. This question arises from one of our assignments, which I have been stuck on for some time. So the problem is stated above.

Comment: Can you please say a bit more about how the question arises, and what is your background? Particularly, it's obvious (for some value of _obvious_) that $f$ is continuous, and $f$ is easily inverted, so a reasonable strategy is to proceed formally, then to go through the argument and justify each step at whatever level of formality is required.

Comment: of course, i'll add it in the edit now.

Comment: This approach looks overly-technical to me, unless you can't use that rational functions (including polynomials) are continuous...?