# Prove that $f(a, b, c) = (a, b - a, \frac{c - a}{b - a})$ defines a homeomorphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, geometry, metric-spaces

Consider the problem given below.

Let

\begin{equation*}
X = \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{C}^3 | a \neq b \neq c \neq a\}
\end{equation*}

be the set of pairwise distinct triples of points in $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$. Each triple $(a, b, c)$ determines a (possibly degenerate) triangle $\triangle a b c$ in the plane. Let

\begin{equation*}
Y = \mathbb{C} \times (\mathbb{C} - \{0\}) \times (\mathbb{C} - \{0, 1\})
\end{equation*}

be the set of triples $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{C}^3$ with $y \neq 0$ and $z \not \in \{0, 1\}$. Give $\mathbb{C}^3 \cong \mathbb{R}^6$ the usual metric topology, and give $X$ and $Y$ the subspace topologies.

Prove that

\begin{equation*}
f(a, b, c) = (a, b - a, \frac{c - a}{b - a})
\end{equation*}

defines a homeomorphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$.

Firstly, what is the usual metric topology on $\mathbb{C}^3$, and; secondly, how do I go about proving that this defines a homeomorphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$?

Comment: The usual metric is the Euclidean one. It has this nice property that addition, subtraction, multiplication and division are all continuous. You can construct the inverse of $f$ explicitly by solving $f(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ equation.

Comment: So since the subspace topology on $Y$ is the same as the usual metric topology on $Y$, and since the usual metric topology on $Y$ is the same as the product topology on Y; I may use the fact that: 1) the continuity of $f$ is equivalent to the continuity of the coordinate functions of $f$; and, 2) the coordinate functions are continuous because of the nice properties that they inherit from the Euclidean metric. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Follow up question.... If $A = \{(a, b, c) \in X | |b - a| \neq |c - b| \neq |a - c| \neq |b - a|\}$ is a subspace of X, then how would I find its connected components? I know that $f(A) = \mathbb{C} \times (\mathbb{C} - \{0\}) \times Z$, for some subspace $Z \subset \mathbb{C} - \{0, 1\}$, but I'm not sure how that's helpful.

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4268305. Coincidence?